# Shrink inner grid column to zero if it has no content

Tags: css, css-grid

In the following example `mid-left` and `mid-right` should equally share space left by all other elements. But if there is only one of them, it should take all this space. It's not known which of them would be present. Supporting of `gap` is NOT needed.

**I can make this only via `:has` selector. How can I make the same thing without it?**

Markup should NOT be changed. Otherwice I would wrap `mid-left` and `mid-right` into container and used `flex` or `grid-auto-columns: 1fr` on it.

Here are 5 examples how it should work:

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "l t  t  t" 2em
                 "l mt mt r" 1fr
                 "l ml mr r" 1fr / 5em 1fr 1fr 5em;
  min-height: 8em;
}

section + section {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.left      { grid-area: l;  background: antiquewhite; }
.top       { grid-area: t;  background: silver;       }
.right     { grid-area: r;  background: antiquewhite; }
.mid-top   { grid-area: mt; background: yellow;       }
.mid-left  { grid-area: ml; background: aquamarine;   }
.mid-right { grid-area: mr; background: lightsalmon;  }

section:not(:has(.mid-left)) {
  grid-template-columns: 5em 0 1fr 5em;
}

section:not(:has(.mid-right)) {
  grid-template-columns: 5em 1fr 0 5em;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-left">Mid left takes half of space</div>
  <div class="mid-right">Mid right takes half of space</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-left">Mid left should take all width</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-right">Mid right should take all width</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-left">Mid left should have equal width even if it has more content</div>
  <div class="mid-right">Mid right</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-left">Mid left</div>
  <div class="mid-right">Mid right should have equal width even if it has more content</div>
</section>
```

PS: Actually I have several divs with `display: contents` on them and the elements `mid-left` and `mid-right` are not on the same level.

PPS: Anyway, I think answers based on provided markup are usefull for future viewers or maybe even for me if I could adopt selectors.

Actually I was not going to add examples with wrappers into the question, but as I was asked, here they are:

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "l t  t  t" 2em
                 "l mt mt r" 1fr
                 "l ml mr r" 1fr / 5em 1fr 1fr 5em;
  min-height: 8em;
}

section + section {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

some-wrapper {
  display: contents;
}

.left      { grid-area: l;  background: antiquewhite; }
.top       { grid-area: t;  background: silver;       }
.right     { grid-area: r;  background: antiquewhite; }
.mid-top   { grid-area: mt; background: yellow;       }
.mid-left  { grid-area: ml; background: aquamarine;   }
.mid-right { grid-area: mr; background: lightsalmon;  }

section:not(:has(.mid-left)) {
  grid-template-columns: 5em 0 1fr 5em;
}

section:not(:has(.mid-right)) {
  grid-template-columns: 5em 1fr 0 5em;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  
  <some-wrapper>
    <div class="top">Top</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
    <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
    <div class="mid-right">Mid right</div>
  </some-wrapper>
  
  <some-wrapper>
    <div class="mid-left">Mid left</div>
  </some-wrapper>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  
  <some-wrapper>
    <div class="top">Top</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
    <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  </some-wrapper>
  
  <some-wrapper>
    <div class="mid-left">Mid left</div>
  </some-wrapper>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  
  <some-wrapper>
    <div class="top">Top</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
    <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
    <div class="mid-right">Mid right</div>
  </some-wrapper>
  
  <some-wrapper>
  </some-wrapper>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  
  <some-wrapper>
    <div class="mid-right">Mid right</div>
    <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
    <div class="top">Top</div>
  </some-wrapper>

  <div class="right">Right</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>

  <some-wrapper>
    <div class="mid-right">Mid right</div>
    <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  </some-wrapper>

  <some-wrapper>
    <div class="mid-left">Mid left</div>
  </some-wrapper>

  <div class="right">Right</div>
</section>
```

[Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1485137/178988)